# Como debo escribir correctamenta los comando esc/pos en c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy imprimiendo texto plano, pero quiero mandar varias comandos esc/pos a mi empresora, pero no se como escribirlos correctamente[image: Este un Comando que quiero mandar pero no escribir correctamente]

Es asi que escribo los comandos

```
Datos.AppendLine("\x1B64n");
```

Comment: Ahí no estas mandando un comando, estas mandando a agregar una linea a tu texto.

Comment: ¿qué se supone que quieres hacer?

Comment: Aquí en esta página hay unos comandos para esc/pos en c#
http://www.sumiquel.com/ftp_todotpv/escpos%20ePSON.pdf

Comment: Aquí conseguí esto puede servirte: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704989/Print-Direct-To-Windows-Printer-EPOS-Receipt